# Next.js derive content type from path extension path/api.xml = text/xml RAILS style

Tags: next.js, vercel

Rails has a nice feature that allows to specify the optional extension in paths like `path/api(.format)` which then inside the handler is passed in as `params.format`.

Is this possible with nextjs routing too for API routes?
I'd like to enable this for all routes basically.

Comment: Is this a static file? If yes, you can move it to `public/` and the content type will be derived...

Comment: No its not. All dynamic.

Comment: @philk have you found any solution to this?

Comment: Looking for this too